# Browsers suddenly prompt to save website as application/x-httpd-lsphp, rather than render page. Htaccess file unchanged. How to fix?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, content-type

Our website worked with no problems. There were no changes, but yesterday it stopped working. When the user visits the site, the browser now prompts the user to download the page. In Firefox, it says:

> "You have chosen to open [page name] which is:
>   application/x-httpd-lsphp from http://our.website.com".

There have been no changes in our site.

Our .htaccess file has not been changed for months. It has 2 relevant parts. This section forces all files without an extension to be rendered by php, while allowing all files with an extension to be rendered normally:

```
<Files *>
ForceType application/x-httpd-lsphp
</Files>
<Files *\.*>
ForceType None
</Files>
```

and this sets the main index page to Start (no extension):

```
DirectoryIndex Start
```

It worked fine for months, then suddenly stopped working

It's PHP Version 5.4.34. Linux, Apache.

We checked with web host support. They don't know what's wrong, so they suggest we should restore the whole site to a version from 1 week before. We'd really prefer not to, though, as we'd lose the last week of data.

Any ideas what happened and how to fix? Thanks...

Comment: Is the mod_lsapi enabled ? This kind of mime type is used with it. If not it should be x-httpd-php.

Comment: @NaeiKinDus. Thanks. x-httpd-php also causes the browser to prompt to download, saying "You have chosen to open [page name] which is: application/x-httpd-php". We changed nothing ourselves, but it just started happening yesterday. Any idea what could have changed to cause the problem?

Comment: If your Apache is enable to load the PHP module, there are several possibilities: your PHP module is not enabled (thus the handler is never called), your PHP installation has a problem (a failed upgrade perhaps), or PHP configuration issues... Did you perform any upgrade, modification vaguely related to PHP, Apache, or web ?

Comment: @NaeiKinDus. Thanks for what you wrote. We took what you said and pushed the server company to give us more help. It turns out that they added litespeed. It couldn't parse extensionless pages x-httpd-lsphp. For anyone who ever sees this in the future, it's x-httpd-php5. Your comment is the correct answer. Thanks again.

Comment: If you could just mark this as answered that could be nice and might help people in the future :) (or add your own finding if my answer is not complete enough).

Comment: Of course :). I didn't want to trouble you to write it up as an answer, but that's great. I marked it as accepted. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summary of the comments:

It was needed to ensure that LiteSpeed was loaded, which was the case (newly installed to be precise).
It turns out that LiteSpeed did not work with extensionless pages, so LeeWenzu had to specify "x-httpd-php5" for the document type.